# Java FlowChart framework for the web

Tags: jakarta-ee, bpmn, flowchart

Do you know any Web FlowChart frameworks for Java ?

What exactly do I mean by "Web FlowChart framework":

- Capable of generating [BPMN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Process_Modeling_Notation) diagrams; (If not BPMN, at least basic flowcharts / graphs that are easily customizable);
- The generated diagrams are easily embeddable in a Java EE (Oracle Adf 11g) application;
- The generated diagrams can be applets / java script / flash, and are user responsive (user can click on the diagrams, etc.) - no statical images .
- The diagram content can be modified / generated at runtime (The application model is data-driven);
- License is not an issue, but still we prefer products with a permissive license model (BSD, MIT, APACHE);

You can give any hints, as we are in the evaluation period, and we want to try as many products as possible.

Do you know any similar solution from Oracle / Sun ?

The framework shouldn't include any business logic. We only needed it to represent data in a fashionable manner.

Answer (score 0):

Another commercial solution is the [yFiles](http://www.yworks.com) suite of diagramming products.
There is an [extension package](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yfiles_ep_ybpmn.html) specifically for BPMN available (and an interactive webstart demo is also [online](http://www.yworks.com/products/demo/yfiles/bpmnEd.jnlp)).

yFiles for Java and AJAX can be used for Applets and specifically in a Java Servlet Context. The more modern [HTML5 solution](http://www.yworks.com/yfileshtml) is based on Javascript only and can thus be used with any server.

The licenses are permissive (perpetual, developer seat based, one-time fee), but it's commercial and not open source.

To my knowledge Oracle does not offer this kind of product (there are very few professional libraries on the market for this kind of task), unless you count the sources of Netbeans, which also includes a graph editor component, although not specifically for BPMN.

Full disclosure: I work for yWorks, but I do not represent my employer on SO.